# Glossary in Moodle: show overview of all terms on one page

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am a beginner in moodle-programming and would like to build a custom module which displays all terms and explanations of a given glossary on one page. Can someone point out, how to begin and accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moodle has a built-in glossary feature that allows glossaries to be added to courses -it's described in the user guide. You will see the ALL option to display all on a single page. They can also be imported from appopriately formatted files like CSV or XML files,search for import glossary from Excel in moodle on moodle.org

Comment: Thanks, i didn't see the "ALL" display. But what i am missing is a kind of summary which tells me how many words are there in the glossary in total, how many words start with A, or how many words did input a certain user. I will open a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641204/count-entries-in-moodle-glossary